# Developing a C++ solid mechanics program

Tags: finite-element, c++, fenics, deal.ii, solid-mechanics

I am a beginner in computational science and programming. I am doing research in non linear solid mechanics analysis and using C++ for coding. I have been exploring various finite element open source programs and saw some nice works like Deal.ii, FEniCS, OOFEM, libmesh. But as a beginner in C++ programming and finite element , documentation of these programs are beyond my comprehension and confusing. I would like to see  some simple object oriented C++ codes for solving finite element problems. My objective is not studying finite element analysis but to understand the implementation of algebra behind it in C++ Object oriented frame work.

Regarding my work, I am clear about the procedures and concepts in my mind. I have made a prototype in MATLAB. Since MATLAB program takes too much time to get the result I decided to switch to C++ considering the ease of future work. But various data structures in C++ makes me troubled to select appropriate storage and structure for nodes, elements, constraints and loads. In MATLAB I imported prepared data (nodes, element connectivity, loads and boundary constraints) from spread sheet and used in built functions for calculations. In the C++ implementation, I am thinking to use a text-file (like in Abaqus/Calculix) for input. How do I implement it?

I am searching for a well commented small finite element program source code for solving plane stress problems, like the kind of programs some university is using for teaching. I went through the book of S D Rajan, Numerical methods in C++ and got some insights about C++ data structures but still I need to go through some source codes for developing my own program. In later stages of my research I can make use of existing finite element libraries like Deal.ii and FEniCS.

Comment: You might want to take a look at FeaTure: https://www.utwente.nl/ctw/tm/research/NSM/software/feature/ It is small enough to be unintimidating but has a fair bit of functionality. A downside is that it doesn't appear to be under active development or have a large community associated with it.

Comment: I don't like C++ very much, as one needs to import libraries to plot figures. What libraries do people use for figures?

Answer (score 4):

Specific answers to this question are probably time-limited.  However, the following general approach (from the great Eric S. Raymond) works very well:

1. Rule of Modularity: Write simple parts connected by clean
   interfaces.
2. Rule of Clarity: Clarity is better than cleverness.
3. Rule of Composition: Design programs to be connected to other programs.
4. Rule of Separation: Separate policy from mechanism; separate interfaces   from engines.
5. Rule of Simplicity: Design for simplicity; add complexity only where you must.
6. Rule of Parsimony: Write a big program only when it is clear by   demonstration that nothing else will do.
7. Rule of Transparency: Design for visibility to make inspection and   debugging easier.
8. Rule of Robustness: Robustness is the child of transparency and   simplicity.
9. Rule of Representation: Fold knowledge into data so program logic can be stupid and robust.
10. Rule of Least Surprise: In interface design, always do the least   surprising thing.
11. Rule of Silence: When a program has nothing surprising to say, it should say nothing.
12. Rule of Repair: When you must fail, fail noisily and as soon as possible.
13. Rule of Economy: Programmer time is expensive; conserve it in preference to machine time.
14. Rule of Generation: Avoid hand-hacking; write programs to write programs when you can.
15. Rule of Optimization: Prototype before polishing. Get it working before you optimize it.
16. Rule of Diversity: Distrust all claims for "one true way".
17. Rule of Extensibility: Design for the future, because it will be here sooner than you think.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a program as much as a big repository of codes. John Burkardt from Florida State University maintains a rich collection of scripts in C++, Matlab and Fortran for a large range of problems. You can check out the [FEM 2D library](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/fem2d_pack/fem2d_pack.html) or go up a level and look at other codes listed there. These have good commenting on them and you can look at the source directly.